# How to direct route to specific lambda kafka consumer?

Tags: apache-kafka, lambda

I have a use case where the client is sending a bunch of events to a service in real time. I am using kafka for event ingestion. Now the kafka producer writes to a topic which contains multiple partitions. Multiple kafka lambda consumers are subscribed to this topic which are in different consumer groups so that they can read all partitions. Each kafka lambda consumer has some business logic which processes events. My idea is to filter event in lambda but it can spawn multiple lambda functions due to asynchronous invocation but might no do actual parsing due to filtering in lambda. is there any way where I can determine based on type of event and direct them to their relevent lambda parsers. Also I want it to make flexible eg: if we add a new lambda parser, we shouldn't make any changes on producer, kafka level.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each of your lambdas are reading the same topic, and are in a unique consumer group, therefore, they will get **all** events.

If you want to subscribe by a type, you will need to use distinct topics for each type, and make your functions subscribe to only those topics.

Rather than run N lambdas, you could run 1 Kafka Streams topology in N JVM container instances, that has the filter and processing logic embedded. When you need to process a new type, you'd redeploy that one app.

Comment: so type can add as we go forward and each type would have a consumer attached to it. I dunt want to create a topic everytime I add a new consumer. how can we embed the logic can you elaborate on this ?

Comment: TL;DR, you need _something_ to deserialize and split events by type. Lambda should not read every event, then decide what to do. In a long-running Kafka Streams job (container or EC2, not lambda), then you can do `stream.filter((k, v) => v.getType().equals("example")).forEach((k, v) => doSomething(k, v));`... Every time you want to process a different type, you need to edit and redeploy that code, or write a new  app with a different filter condition. Or you can `filter(...).to("type-topic")`, then Lambda would read **from that topic**